# AS3 Workers : Received Object throwing " Type Coercion failed" error

Tags: actionscript, worker

I have created a worker class to Parse a Collada file(Alternativa3d Engine).

I am sending dae/xml file to Worker class and parsing it. While receiving it at Main class, got an error saying  "Type Coercion failed".

Here is the code.

Main Class: Sending Data

```
if (bgWorkerX.state == WorkerState.RUNNING)
        {
            var _b:ByteArray = (new modelX() as ByteArray);
            var xml:XML = (new XML(_b.readUTFBytes(_b.length)));
            bgWorkerCCX.send(["START_PARSING", XParser]);
        }
```

Main Class : Receiving Data

```
if (!resultCX.messageAvailable)
        {
            return;
        }
        var result:String = resultCX.receive(true);
        if (result == "SUCCESS")
        {

            var txt3:TextField = new TextField();
            txt3.text = "Parsed result : " + Mesh(resultCX.receive(true)); //ERROR LINE : TYPE COERCION FAILED.
        }
    }
```

Worker Class :

```
private function handleCommandMessage(event:Event):void
    {
        if (!commandChannel.messageAvailable)   {
            return;
        }

        var message:Array = commandChannel.receive() as Array;

        if (message != null && message[0] == "START_PARSING")
        {
            StartParsing(XML(message[1]));
        }
    }

    private function StartParsing(xml:XML):void
    {
        parser = new ParserCollada();
        parser.parse(xml);
        resultChannel.send("SUCCESS");
        resultChannel.send(parser.getObjectByName('mainbody') as Mesh);
    }
```

Anybody has idea how to convert similar kind of objects to desired type?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ByteArray.writeObject`...

`ByteArray.readObject` methods for that...

I also faced this issue but not sure if is possible to do.

Let me know please if you succeed to solve it.